# GP-Tool: Detect if running in background or foreground ? (ArcObjects)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, geoprocessing

I got a geoprocessing tool which I want to prevent from running in background, due to some weird crashes that happens.

Is it possible to programmatically detect if background processing is enabled ? (tried to look into environments with no luck).

I know there is a mechanism for this in 10.1, but I am stuck with 10.0 SP 5.

Comment: I guess you could work around this by investigating the running process name. It should be ArcSOCP.exe or RuntimeLocalServer.exe (depending on ArcGIS version, I haven't tried this).

Comment: Yep, I keep killing them once & while.. not sure if I dare rely on that though.